# How to get count of line of codes in Odoo 11?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, odoo-13

I am trying to get the total count of lines of codes in my custom modules. it tried the below command.

```
./odoo-bin cloc --conf=odoo11.conf -d odoo10
```

Here `odoo.conf` addons path to default addons and custom addons.

But I am getting the below error:

> Unknow command 'cloc'

How to solve this?

Comment: IIRC the cloc function was introduced with Odoo 12 or 13 and was never backported. To get a reasonably good value try to isolate your custom modules in a folder and use the typical cloc tools for your OS like [cloc which can be used with many OS](https://cloc.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @CZoellner, I also tried with Odoo13, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The `cloc` tool is in the odoo starting from version 13.

You can use it or even version 16 to count your code. You cant install v11 modules to the newer Odoo base. So you have to use `cloc` tool by the path.

The `-v` is for verbose output. It lists all counted files.

```
./odoo-bin cloc -v -p /path/to_modules/module
```

It can count all the modules together as well.

```
./odoo-bin cloc -p /path/to_modules
```